# Cluster node is completely down, but OEM status is reporting Agent Unreachable

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-enterprise-manager

We have a 4 node oracle cluster in 11G.  Our Oracle Enterprise Manager Cloud Control 12c dashboard is showing the icon for the hosts (XXXXXXXDB031 and XXXXXXXXXXXDB032) as "Agent Unreachable" when both are actually face down.  Does anyone know why it would show that status instead of "Down"?  Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that both the databases are down *and* there's a problem with the agent or host?  If you bring the databases up does the status change to Up?

Comment: Turns out it was something like that, the agent went down first, so there were no status changes after that and when the host went down, nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

The agent went down first, so there were no status changes after that and when the host went down, nothing changed.